# Problems using maven with git

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I am now trying to release a simple project on Maven, when I set up the configuration and start to build in the eclipse, it shows the error

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] /bin/sh: git: command not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

As a result, I was expecting there might be some problems with my git. But I can correctly run git in my terminal, and I can even commit and push the code to my github (with eclipse), so I think git should still be installed correctly (Otherwise how can it push code onto github?). Does anyone has suggestions where should I check to figure out the bug? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using maven-release-plugin? Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Actually I fix it later, I had to add the path to the git in the eclipse interface, the PATH environment showed in the terminal variable seems does not work in the eclipse.